# How can I prevent Guzzle 3 from URLEncoding an Operation Parameter?

Tags: php, url, uri, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 3 to work with a Hypermedia HTTP API and having some issues with using URL paths as parameters.  The service will return URL paths to access resources, and is mostly working except that the parameterized path is being URLEncoded.

Here's a sample of the Operation in the Service Description

```
"getWidget": {
  "uri": "{path}",
  "summary": "Get Widget",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "responseType": "class",
  "responseClass": "Service\\Responses\\Widget",
  "parameters": {
    "path": {
      "location": "uri"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm executing the operation by doing:

```
$client = WidgetClient::factory(array('base_url' => 'example.com'));

$args = array('path' => '/widget/abc123');
$command = $client->getCommand('getWidget', $args);
$result = $command->execute();
```

When executed the client requests: `http://example.com/%2Fwidget%2Fabc123` rather than `http://example.com/widgetabc123`

I've traced the parameter processing down to `UriTemplate::expandMatch()` which performs the `rawurlencode($variable)` call that encodes the parameter--but I can't see a clear way to avoid the encodign.

So, with Guzzle 3 and its Service Descriptions, how can I pass a URL path as a parameter without it being URLEncoded?

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround (I'm hoping there's a better approach) I'm subscribing to the `client.create_request` event and modifying the path to remove the encoding.  This is the initial version, it'll get cleaned up before it's final:

```
public function onClientCreateRequest(Event $event)
{
    /** @var Request $request */
    $request = $event['request'];
    if (empty($request)) {
        return;
    }

    $url = $request->getUrl(true);
    if (empty($url)) {
        return;
    }

    $path = $url->getPath();
    $path = rawurldecode($path);
    $path = str_replace('//', '/', $path); 

    //$url->setPath($path);
    $request->setPath($path);
}
```